# Bootstrap alerts with laracasts/flash

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, flash

My problem is displaying alerts with laracasts/flash. I'm getting this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD7E3.png)

But i don't want to "flash" it on the top after redirecting, but equally to the navbar. Any ideas?

Kind Regards, Tom.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laracasts/flash

> If you need to modify the flash message partials, you can run:
>
> ```
> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider"
> ```

Comment: I did this, but I cannot "force" this alert to behave like I want it. :(

Comment: You can make it behave literally any way you like - you have full control over the JS and HTML - by moving the `@include('flash::message')` and editing the partials and JS code. You can also do a fully custom solution if you prefer.